# Replace extra spaces, tab and new line between delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Data output file is having multiple line of records separated by new line. In each row, the columns are separated with delimiter `|`.

Trying to replace all extra whitespaces, tabs, newline characters in each column between delimiter.
Each row data will end with "&*"

Data:

```
char1   |  char2 |
        char3|char  4 &*
char11
       |  char   12 |char13|char14 &*
char21           |  char22 |char23|  char24 &*
```

Roles:

- Trailing Spaces/Tabs need to be removed; then
- Join the lines if they starts/ends with a `|`
- Squeeze repeated whitespaces.
- Skip new line after "&*"

Result:

```
char1|char2|char3|char 4
char11|char 12|char13|char14
char21|char 22|char23|char24
```

Code what I have now is for replacing tab, need to change this to have new line and extra space.

```
sed  -i 's/[ \t]\+|/|/g' DataStats0914.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E '
    :a /\s*&\*\s*$/ !{ N; s/\n//; ta; };
    # read "N"ext line and join (s/\n//) except "!" lines that ends with "&*" chars;
    s/&\*//g;
    # also remove these chars "&*" too 
    s/\s*\|\s*/|/g;
    # remove whitespaces around "|" char as well
' <(tr -s '\t ' ' ' <infile)
```

comments-free command below:

```
sed -E '
    :a /\s*&\*\s*$/ !{ N; s/\n//; ta; }; 
    s/&\*//g;       
    s/\s*\|\s*/|/g;
' <(tr -s '\t ' ' ' <infile)
```